# Having a file outside of the latex project update whenever I recompile the latex project

Tags: compiling, multiple-files, filesystem-access, vscode, folders

So right now I have a bunch folders for all the work I do in Latex organized by subject matter. Each one of these consists of the various latex projects I have for each subject. The folder that holds all of these is called the "work" folder. I then have another folder titled "finished projects" which again contains a folder for each subject, but this time in each subject folder I just have the finished pdf.

Sometimes, I go back and notice a mistake or typo I didn't check before and so I go back and fix it, but then I have to reupdate the finished projects folder, and it's just kinda annoying to do. I am wondering, is there way to do this automatically, so that each time I update a latex project, the finished project pdf updates as well?

Edit: I am using vscode as an editor to run latex and edit my projects.

Comment: that depends how you run latex, if you simply run pdflatex on the commandline you need to copy teh pdf at the end, but if ypu run latex via an editor menu pipeline or via make or arara or latexmk or a batch file or shell script, you can simply add the copy to the command sequence/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I run Latex using some vscode setup that I don't fully understand, I just followed some instructions

Comment: you should edit the question to mention vscode (and tag it) as the question is purely about vscode and not at all about latex (I don't use vscode so much, but someone will answer)

Comment: Instead of copying the files, use links (shorcuts) in the final folder.  When the original changes, the shortcut will access the updated version.

Comment: @JohnKormylo the shortcut doesn't let me actually access the file when I back things up to the cloud. I basically have my final projects saved to my icloud, and my projects stored locally, so that I can access pdfs from my ipad

Comment: Yeah, backup software is a pain to get right.  After I had a disk crash I discovered that none of the .tex, .ccp or .h files (the most important files on my computer) had been backed up.  You would think that expanding shortcuts would be an option.

Comment: Use a file system which supports hard links or back up software which follows whatever kind of link your file system supports. Or (I guess depending on your OS) you can also set things up to watch a particular directory or directories for changes and take some action if a file in one of those directories alters e.g. I have a service set up to re-copy certain files to directory A if they change in directory B.

Comment: @cfr Do you know how I could do that on a mac?

Comment: @Chris Which? It's a long time since I used a mac, but I'm pretty sure you could use a hard link. Remove the copy of the PDF from the finished directory. Then `ln <path to PDF in working directory> <path to PDF in finished directory>`. I'm sure you can watch a directory for changes, too, but I don't know, off hand, which tool would be best. You don't need anything mac-specific, I don't think, because these files won't have any specifically mac attributes. (I don't even know if files on macs still can have those.)

Comment: @Chris If you use continuous syncing, it's almost certainly what your cloud syncing service is doing: setting a watch on the directory etc.

Comment: You might be able to implement some custom logic around a file system watcher like `inotify` on Linux, but this clearly is out of scope for TeX.SX.